# How to integrate SQL Server CE with Enterprise Library 5 DatabaseFactory?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce-4, enterprise-library-5

I'm getting an

> "Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
>   Database, key "" "

exception with my `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()` whenever I reference the default database to a SQL Server CE

I tried checking if the problem is just my .dll reference, which I was able to prove wrong because I was still able to connect to a real SQL Server 2008 db.

Here's my config:

```
<configSections>
<section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="sqlCEDB"/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="sqlCEDB"
           connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\sqlCEDB.sdf;Password='somepassword'"
           providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here's how I create the database instance:

```
private Database db;

protected internal Database DB
{
   get 
   {
      if (db == null)
         db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
      return db; 
   }
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**

change config property
solved: providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"

Comment: solved: providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"

Comment: You should update your question with your solution! Edit the question and add a "SOLUTION:" section to it, and show the proper config used that works

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

change config property solved: providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
             requirePermission="false"/>
</configSections>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="sqlCEDB"/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="sqlCEDB"
             connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\sqlCEDB.sdf;Password='somepassword'"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>
```